# Detect if the browser has swipe navigation gestures enabled with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, gesture

I have JS swipe gestures for browsers without swipe navigation. However, for browsers with native swipe gestures, it'll sometimes trigger both the native gesture and my JS gesture.

It seems like each browser implements swipe gestures differently, so it's too hard to disable the native swipe gestures. Is there a way to detect if native swipe gestures are enabled? Then, I can disable my JS swipe gestures.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check is this device has touch devices with one of three variants?

```
let isTouch1 = window.matchMedia("(pointer: coarse)").matches;
let isTouch2 = navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0;
let isTouch3 = 'ontouchstart' in window;
```

Comment: This would match all touch devices including ones without swipe navigation?

Comment: @LeoJiang yes..